# How do I search this in MySQL and get result?

Tags: php, mysql

table1

```
name   | designation
------------------
john   | engineer
mathew | IT consultant
Neil   | SAP
Tom    | webdeveloper
david  | egineer
kane   | engineer
```

I do have above same names in a text file too. when I search names from text file then I need to grab designation of that name then search with that designation and list names with that designation.

for example if I search by `John` then I want get result as `john = david,kane`

how can I do this with PHP and MySQL??

Comment: What's if you search for `mathew`, would it return a empty string?

Comment: that was an example I have more than 600k names and details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  t2.name
FROM
  table1 t1
INNER JOIN
  table1 t2
ON
  t1.designation = t2.designation
WHERE
  t1.name = 'John'
AND
  t2.name != 'John'
```

Comment: You also need to add `and t2.name != 'John'`

Comment: oops confusing statement..can you elaborate little more??

Comment: @limo, Basically it does an SQL join over the same table, the tables are aliased so you can remove duplicate entries using the last line.